# Поднять среднюю колонку

Tags: css

Есть три колонки:

```css
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {display: table; line-height: 0; content: '';}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}

.fl_l {float: left}

.tariff {margin-right: 15px; background: #000000; width: 100px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="fl_l tariff">
        test
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l tariff">
        test
        <br />
        test
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l tariff">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juaotfve/

Каким образом поднять среднюю колонку так, только нормальным способом?

```css
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {display: table; line-height: 0; content: '';}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}

.fl_l {float: left}

.tariff {margin-right: 15px; background: #000000; width: 100px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="fl_l tariff">
        test
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-top: -18px;" class="fl_l tariff">
        test
        <br />
        test
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l tariff">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/juaotfve/1/

Если непонятно о чём речь, то скриншот ниже, на котором средний блок красиво выделяется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так, если не критично использовать именно float:

```
.row {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.row div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xuavt0op/5/

Comment: то, что нужно. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

> Каким образом поднять среднюю колонку так, только нормальным способом?

Вопрос в том, что вы понимаете под нормальным способом. Отрицательный `margin` – вполне нормальный подход. Можно для среднего блока вместо `margin-top: -18px` прописать `position: relative; bottom: 18px;`.

Если вас интересует реализация смещения без ухода за границу родительского блока, то тут ничего кроме `margin-top` для контейнера в голову не приходит.

Если же вы имеете в виду, что-то другое, то уточните. Будем думать.

Придумал ещё вот такой способ:

```
<style type="text/css">
.clearfix {
    display: table;
}

.clearfix > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100px;
}

.clearfix > div > div.content {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="content">test</div>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <div class="content">
            test<br />test
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="content">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но он сильно проигрывает варианту @11111000000.

Comment: без margin'а хотелось бы. Уверен, что это не то, что должно быть. К тому же подбирать самому значение не хочется.

Comment: и Вам спасибо :) Ответ полезен.

Comment: @ModaL у меня фантазия до методов забивания гвоздей микроскопом богата. :)